# How to get Polygon for a city from GeoJSON?

Tags: geographics

Following the instruction from the answer here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183248/getting-polygon-boundaries-of-city-in-json-from-google-maps-api

I download the required city data in `GeoJSON`.

`http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/index.py?id=4263150`

```
regina = Import["get_geojson.txt","RawJSON"];
```

Next I look at the format in which mathematica stores polygon data:

```
Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Ontario","Canada"}]["Polygon"]/.{Polygon[GeoPosition[x__]]:>Dimensions@x}
```

So I get the coordinate data from the `JSON` in the right format as follows:

```
data = Query[First@*"geometries",1,"coordinates"]@regina
```

But when I try to convert it into `GeoPosition` I get the following error:

```
GeoPosition@data
```

> GeoPosition::ltrng: Invalid latitude specification
>   {{-104.65837970000000,-104.65687330000000,-104.64605760000001,-104.645,-104.64424790000000,-104.641415499999994,-104.64117950000001,-104.64115800000000,<<35>>,-104.50330000000000,-104.50322160000000,-104.49920109999999,-104.49840829999999,-104.49734650000001,-104.492221799999996,-104.49219340000001,<<178>>}}.

What is going wrong here? Does Mathematica has a different coordinate system for `GeoPosition`?

Comment: Nevermind, just had to reverse the coordinates to make it work. But if anyone know a better source for getting Geo polygon data for the cities in Canada that would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) the [`"GeoJSON"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GeoJSON.html) `"Data"` directly from either your downloaded files or the Interwebs.

```
polyData = 
 Import["http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_geojson.py?id=4263150&\params=0", 
  {"GeoJSON", "Data"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This returns the data as a list of key-values.  [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) can operate on list.

```
GeoGraphics[{Green, EdgeForm[Blue], Query["Geometries"]@polyData}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.