# How to add the custom polygon to Entities?

Tags: geographics, entity

Suppose I get the polygon data using the method here:

[How to get Polygon for a city from GeoJSON?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211902/how-to-get-polygon-for-a-city-from-geojson)

Now how do I add it to the `Entities` so they make use of it? I tried the following:

```
Unprotect[Entity];
Entity["City",{"Mississauga","Ontario","Canada"}]["HasPolygon"]=True;
Entity["City", {"Toronto", "Ontario", "Canada"}]["HasPolygon"]=True;
Entity["City",{"Mississauga","Ontario","Canada"}]["Polygon"]=Polygon[GeoPosition[CompressedData["blahblahblah"]]];
Entity["City",{"Toronto","Ontario","Canada"}]["Polygon"]=Polygon[GeoPosition[CompressedData["blahblahblah"]]];
Protect[Entity];
```

Now if I do:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["City",{"Mississauga","Ontario","Canada"}]->2,Entity["City",{"Toronto","Ontario","Canada"}]->1}]
```

does not produce the result like follows from the custom Polygon.

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Ontario","Canada"}]->2,Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Quebec","Canada"}]->1}]
```

---

For reproducibility here is the Polygon data I have:

For Mississauga:

```
Polygon[
    GeoPosition[CompressedData["
    1:eJxd2nk4Vk/cP3CKZE8kuwqRpSJtluzZ15uoaCGUnZQ1a4XKGiKULZFEtiR0
    y1bZSiWkFMmSLCkU8bzneX5/fK/fdfHH6zpzzpkz85nPzJxzb7Z1N7NfTUND
    Q4t/3VU0NPijUbmqF6vfqqVKs2eTev8shfpqwVtKAb7ScCCvD95Yf2SdGHzv
    tYnOe3ipkluACxY5y9/QBTsMG8ovv9RSLY4s5GqDb753UR2A3+oF6tbBCu5r
    /5bARupjzFnwJv6E3IoXOL/9zInfPynUHSZmJ2jhVmvJkLOw1cQV75vPtVQT
    +gszd8F1TArOtHD95mLbthkK1W/ajareoqUao89sqAMfLadxLWzWUm1jLont
    mKZQ3d1WPVOGuT/6G8bCznV35kebtFRfJao32cAWO07x/WzUUn3OUhxcOkWh
    /hu9srYCHrQWag6G9SeZNVRg02BbxnXw4uD8Bw34R2HNdlaYtpVmzT647sEG
    EVrYyDFMiRumOfb358dJCnX09a1+GliUb9K1EZ73NwudbNBS3fflsdk9mLkx
    y/U7HKkfo3gHPl7ewjwGJ9/f8SgTdthdtXYEfrZwpj8Nli09FTMMv96e5JoM
    B4fPjQ/BKVV/D8XBgirFb3JgTWetNDv4W+rPwJNwyYeHW+Th6pHig9KwxNTQ
    aTZy/RTRz5thvbDWujWwwLQ5//wzPM+RXJXxHxTqMR+60AFY2ZyR/gMccbX/
    zTtYwWTmxVt4B1ObeRdsPxVwpQv+mpBa3wGrJ91UfgWbMjS8LIUDdm47UAfr
    u4ueuwsvteqGV8JWPYLpqbDLqoccReR+E7YqO+HxVauL7OHNzpZyHLBvPOWS
    CZxSkFvwp15LVfoKa5sqvN5E6VkjvLndSl4QLnIsYq2GF3//+bQBZvs4wZ4I
    l3s2HlmaoFD3qzhVucK9HfOUIdiahu+OPjyzu3p/K/ynRGLPTvjIH+pYFVz2
    nJ9eBnY0jamqhHMtZMYk4Hvxd+fKYEHN5mVWeM9ZHacsWDXHe+w4bM9ftfoc
    HPF2meciXLnh0KWTsJ/pibwEOJueNfsILDUj9qcSZtnOon0Q1muz6h2Cw4fr
    rsrAi7Z39v0j5Td0iG6C+xZstkigPYK++/1YC0+tkebShK+193z5851CtZ/q
    1tCCO56uUiZWdJrpOAirrH3kvAB3nVOqPwwfcO9MmYRlLmgoucJcngPsX+E5
    uu3ygbBoySfDfnK+f6npNTjygUVbFyyQGRudBv+84FnwEnYS0JJ9C+cb3V8o
    hLepFMyNweUhT40y4fwaR7dOOFGuICsavu2mxfCCHF9W1I4i5S/ffN8CZxdN
    nY6EhepmjjyAmd2ODJyH9Vt1akm8BM1Km3nBHLIve87BnBW9/4xh5qKUo85w
    6KDLgA58Zk9swwm4gD+8QA2O2iDqsp3Em4FthRCslvq9lwfW3231kZ083/OD
    ARthJl2H32ywhe8XHk6Y50kPOwv8hGVlbA3M7fuRgw6mrlL2I/2h23kg8984
    hcp4iprzHva7z8v7FWYwSNZtgBmbBY53w3NpX7Mr4JPcffvb4YcK7TZ5JD6H
    r29ogFPZMm75wC/bt57PgV9oq+U5wxGleafT4EPx/LF2cBbj4/kkOHdiyNIW
    5jRz3Uq8pU2H5yQ8N7BfLxG2fT93/n/jubTV+hJsl+TjrwdPtISWXoTnufQ8
    5OELPM4vvGH/8LcJu2BPCbltxGpfsnV54NSoCzYn4b154tIzVC3Vxj2zvw/C
    Zzft3jsNT3ZqaRDfkl6XMgifl/V6ogTTVZz9XQfHsC3Li8Kv9QP2Z8PiUlI/
    15Hrdxmkh8LszBV5f8YoVM2rLZlu8DkbSsAEvEpwft4OZnvgzj0Mb9x82ZEC
    W7BkJfbBY28k/2rAY0Ii453w68BtNzbDU092iVbBw4liAxxwUcC520VwYbqp
    ETvMKZCfUQiLPS792/sU88dnlbAIOH2Y9ep9WOiGePNp2IHZTCEbtjTb13YS
    TtQtLYuGnaibxigwy2B+6FV4x+Z3Dmbwn/2/2kLhy8mvqvThwIh4Lm2YRS9C
    WQTeOfd4tyZclHdQYzNcLV5uqg53OVstCMPFF3PpheACKU1pBvi7kcAwPXys
    3MVsbhTza8Iotb0O+eVxx7lXxLdZmRJhTXrlKwXwwFOhKneY8bbZyzjYeJDH
    zR6W7TmdGAXzyp2Wk4F3CSbNnYQrSmzihmpR/zDn6zvgNQafuz/CXevP7ZSG
    02XbGPvgfS9LVCXhlKzkqxlwt9CcOi28N8bqqjHsq6x89P4Ihaqd2pD7AGaV
    c2Mf+Uahxkj6SdGi/jq+suGOsPWGn2aLaP/VG8/N68HtvpXZEphvkhp1hq1h
    3+zgj5qYH3fFWgbsgm+cybw1BEtt8ctoGKZQP/eUjchhvs7bZ6V7Du5nTMvz
    hrkouyr2wFzmfzR64KmYa+++fUU+fmmygYL5vnXxOiUZlr5vH1gAd3EHqvTB
    74q9DyhhvbB49vz7INgy9w1dGtxPn3jjIKzglLzhLVxz/MTDL0MUak7Ed9uv
    8Bs61dYC+LrIggId1h/XvH/zXoYv7qJU7IMPNTG5usN2XuW/SmEFpYszFPiH
    cco3FqxnPLjYP7HCQdzT7xnhWrpVC6vg3IE6tnSU75hf2FY2SKH2VLb/6YDZ
    XI9OJcB3d6kJMaP8ZcHm3KdwfNMEvxEcpcBzKBne/TdiqBi+aZRVEA1zefCG
    PoMNQrmta+EO+/Lb3XDOHMeDSliwMjJ8AD4pFH2LuDNE2H8ebmLj1WqC+TT0
    /q15+X/juxm+s6LKJQ73FcZG1JH7Se1R2wE/pFv7rgYu2XbQQAXmn1ebIceF
    yrJrtGDfH12XG2Ax9r+RRrAdsxrbS1iLPZDlEEzN101qh6P2cGifhs/VS0p0
    w58lfzn4wYrHs3d+gmntF35dgI/ll34iFkjplyiFd8qMX++Hiw++PtYDN7eE
    CfbBB6avcXyFv6atr+iFbc/Txy+S+pXFx/2AFWq6E/mwXm22oKasRfvL0p6K
    FoZX37R7uw5m6Mk+sRn2q59p5oSfprn1Eistxa3nhj+ucNyQgSe+OgaR8gnr
    0oJUYIvLnnvJ9XjLv+/XhHv/7mqnJ/ET1C5hAM/Knskg/S2XwrdkBUvLJfUu
    oj6bTbQ57GCDZfHg+cH/l/9hOUavQnL8xsMlcw84b+7CdVqcn2aakh4M28Xs
    +M4OM+7ltbgMq603vbsR7ohSLo+Fj5+1khKFlXm7biTCu0YVNMRJfE7v/JHW
    +n/xvA0OfOQ3lAuv9byySwoOLqKlqYS9jC19pOHS4byNzf85fmnqH2sfvFzr
    /n4rvPtZ/Nxv8vxU5U5h+EVnliNbm5ZqhYx7mSD8PpQnejNxzj5t4jaXgzVS
    8JVs09ZNsMJS3+2d8PGxzU9F4IbCNDU5+FaQyUZSPxrjleX98OLHS/MO8EbP
    aUUlWGG1yA5n0n+DBjYa8IN8n7ue8CH2lAgD2LApcIc3zF+V/8QSNlI82HAW
    Fp4v6o6Cc39b67uS/u5qykuC+wqOibiR+n7uYcuC/ZrtCj3g9Kgx9fvwlhKJ
    D+fh+kp51wo4c4vyYgg8O5s0VwNHHvbjjIbj+OXvPYMTPoXqx8Mj8iV/n8P/
    TkhqJ5DnK2hKfgs7YoOUCBde/OjwmVjMTIV4dmiHzDicbnclPInES0+D4RK8
    xuPM92T4l3SRFHM7xoeoc8MNONE41pUXznsrNpQC33dp3CcK+9OaXk2HH7cz
    LUrDIith13PgueYj0XtgFpNT8w9gq4O9HMpwRZKhewVsKMugpg3/WjqTUw0f
    Ht3fYwrv6jN2fkrif6qw/QjM0Ht66hlp3+vsV21hjmvh+i0we8DBFn9Y/UUU
    fz9cvVpKOQqW1LmQMwJHNHRRY+GzP7dwTsONDnuCbsAjN3yuzsGfZIK9M+F4
    iuSNJdKfnZO7C+BXx7aE0yI/j8ZdqXgAswVFaDPAmWGnzYphwxWdFmb4d2Ym
    VxFsKSHziB2mZcjRIU6uPcq+AWY7PcZUCUfWW3aKwv2vcx9Xwz+3HQ3eCkcw
    Hm6rg2tfX5gSg63/Kn1/Cs9umMwjznyV9awFpjyULRaBV0yHm97AZdMm7pth
    34zTpX2wUISDBjk+Iv0vaYBc/7YoJ7n+5eUH3kPwUojpdUk4fVPmw2HSn8f2
    Ht0BW6wPMvoG93WfkJKDh3veqZDyxYKywrvhPoGRPV/gi5N7g/fBP0e/3yKO
    yTL7oARfMk/TJdez9TqsqAq/5rxkMErau9Y1Tx2uUH4XOA0XvtVW1IU3+6kz
    /YH1AsJ3GJD78fO30ndgfTRNQ28Ic7KaTXPB4w9lVhvBaxeChYWJz5y/TsxY
    yHJAAu7V7VlPyt/PMTbZAUc+DRXVhrNZqWs04cEf6fUKsPdFxwwDmE5iaS15
    vtCjPrPmsPY7+xHSXq0RiyKOsH1e+TI3qe8R7lXusCinvthGcr+4JQF/eGJ3
    yhc+WMRz/FgY/FRFL560/8znjyGX4G+rlNgkYAM6+v3hsK5Z5J498GdhmjBi
    L/egBk3yfPyDbFdgX6GtUibwC48vwzFwH6ebxiHS3uYfRdJgSpfQFRt4Yl/v
    ybvwwWk+4+NwO+VZFRVONn/UeBTmX44K+QPXCSq5UeCHpS7pqzu1VDc0DguS
    9n11akWJFXZxim0n9+/1408ThLM5F/xI/6z8ssgXhS1oRjZpkPqE+XLKwS9d
    4nTJ+kTWJfyFBlwk4R6vBRv5aDw9Csc6jzKT46vT9we7wYfNJg+Q9o8PVXoS
    COer1m8i97N5eO74RTiwuDlIkcSHlPmPKPiftv4Vefi0TuveeLj2/ZECWTIe
    oln35cFLw5MdJP4YW2M0ymDZBzbBe8l40jDpo/7nuEDYgYnPcOW/Lxmkf48/
    l/86BhuKGbaT+LbdmPkcawtV3t10LtLwePMJp2m42No9bRu81T0kdQqOFth1
    k4yXEZ/fl77D3pzOdwVI+0+cS5+Atw/lrSH9X1BAFSXns+Q40ZP4cOExNlqG
    t1Loc9aT9t4SosrySkt1uL/fiAOmVN/L3g43lLBuJflhaqOVyz5YZiff6DrY
    098rX+E/5ZVtf/WrwxniGn/J9WSjziQZw5z9OQkkn0i+UBCwgXdOcf8g8eq9
    KW7aFi604ewi9fNqO33TAa72VHMRhp2j51PPwD0TPxSlYLMn1XVOsJyV5z3S
    frWX+CSdYc1OH1oyfo8PKM+R8gqnHh/VgZ/2qoU4wnwm7gfJePOW//fcDl6z
    Wy6IxG9ZSk+gNXz+duS4GXzHWuq7DiwdXCdjBd9QPiWmBkftlI+2JuvluuQs
    RfhhVJv1CTh2Sq2OPP9qU7VY2/84+IHLu1Pwugch6srwdevD/1xIvrif2qwK
    v9LsmfYm+cHCaY54psDsjD88UG8sQOybdCSRrLcf3tGmkPNfUBZ5w+GMtD1D
    8qS89cWOOFjfit9OHHbJ4OzOggdFbPVE4QoBjaMFJP8GXk0Rga0WNEcfwj2H
    D/QLw0pKaCFYZey2ogCcGn81oBb+ZFH+iQsm29NnJL7fZXxcB5eG61m3wNz7
    byexw8rBffkd8L1A71gOmI4ldP07kh9ONryRIv3JNXNtApYQOmlL6u9DERPj
    wf6jwXfjfguYSTFAUBxOt1b/dQS+mJljIQPXsqzjPg5fy2MzlIf3OylanyTX
    y7SyUYa1eH6vnIBHglfnasNnXhwQcYFP1s55Hob3vP2UHETae816d19Ydk1A
    VRTsoMlWeQE+ff7j0XiYslj3IgT2qGsxToUVNcQVQuF3Vo6b82CvvUOxpDyz
    6xTjc/jwNzsZb/is41aeDpjhpNu8F5ya5q45/x+HBT6NoH2tpfq3L4aO7L/i
    DzOYroW3cfWYnYd3rtm0wg0b0/fPBsLKJGHAl2ePd/vDk08uPDSDkc6TSf0i
    rcouOsM9vhYspHzXXxrdC/DCSluAD9yTcPtWJPyKU/I6ud8dlwnXGJgi8msX
    sSObrkwivIN6QIF4cFH6czFcNJ42Hgw76VlavIUl6nYzx8JRmU1FH2F/yxTe
    eLhtSj51Bja/zB2UBHcO11Ss6kL799Vwp8KXj6bq08NfssKjbsIWw7KPGeCC
    T+fiM+D8pIxeRph32dc8Cz5Y0FHOBnPYDTHnkv5JbzblItd7EVdHrFB4T2kr
    rDE7NZYJj334eEwGHrL5+r/n31Y4tE0Zvh0h2pgHs5ljRoZXPZr8VgDrCA0N
    a8LJbLKP78OxYTOCB+GXG8KlS+BtasFZ2nCH09aLZfC+weAv+rDszem8Spiv
    bUOiFSyIBcETmH3lr5wtbC1hzE6FN+0f0vKA3cfz2V+QeHx07E04vLH1QO8n
    eOsp2cXL8D3D+aRBmEHLqDoSZvE07RqFy19tE4mC3/Y8bpyA6yXmZ0j5oz3b
    n8+QeOd7HeELdzsUldJgf8/t46VkQZ5X5TkrH8xXvOO5AcyddcFUnHi/g7wh
    eX7tVax7YF13Tl1j+H1gXr4mrL1Z1MEUdsy2szWCa650p5Hn0dfiPWEBW1EL
    yp3g01bY2cGbxM67upP7cUt0nIfFEuvWecHPchcWLsLqJfeOBcEPOrodIuHQ
    6Lit5PltuDnTYuHptVWyEXCdr8nNG7Dw/YpvF+AXH45+uANTDeO2BMJMalbv
    S+Hq82UmxDpyhT5VcLZgaBRpn3VC6+3qYM+7vPNXYe2rPW3N8LJD7Vlyv5c5
    /Cdfw/0ljz6FwHxit7J74V10lfsvwvIsjZaf4dNdtLnx8OKWLBnyviV8utQj
    B75rsOnDKHxV3JPlEenfMPXZKfjM3LBnLbyty+rQb9jelu5WE1zt0Z08DUfO
    eqx6Q47fOuM7Bh/zSkhf9UZLtTVB71knnLN+1GYNXFHh/aQd1sl6/YwJ9v9e
    atQKs1+SjJOHK9nKlMrh2PodNxXgWf+rgyVwbanDU11Yb6AiKR9u+jbUZwJ3
    ejwuyYXXyvR1HYanL65uvg2nC9L5OsBhRxzfp8AVBlKSEXBBxGnvCFigWr73
    JtzcX3ExEK5jvqNaAlcPrZ7xgIunhBbLYe8yFRM30p6TVy41k/uXlkWTeFAl
    CR2OWrm0w4bUj9G7fwCerzS+cAj+7uGdNAlna49YkvjatKVv1zQ8/uerlyEs
    5BWTNAuH2HXe0ofXrzGf/AX/Gzr7kbzfei6jlvUH/kHRVNIh8Z4QZrP6Lc7P
    L2fXgMMi/RZ5YLHc4Ot74WGdZ7yWMCt9C3UDvOLp2HoMDuksP8MBf6IbkL8A
    pxXVfF0h+aqjLCcMltWfubtE8jlTuFw0rPDhR+McvP38IYc7cKLIg6Ix2ItJ
    Se0+3DV58N0wmY8MRZUfwvzyxoxDJP+vaFtXkvMlao5/hiX6L99/AfdJ+lh0
    k/G8r8q7DS5s4B96S/J74AH3TlhE3dX+DRzcnaXSC2ef+xPQAQuNWm6bhcVH
    /OOfkvdzPyRzl2BKQZBeNUwf9WOS9p2WqlSBW9Qj+NruRxkc8GGfQYliWLzx
    EbMEvLYmTIQcL9/SdFQdnhkRW0fyVXRyfvhJmK4+cgvJVzOHRxPjYduUqr+k
    vuG7FhabYI248PXf4Ko31xa1urE/uMYjzYz2ZP2SYm8Mv9huO8YKn9JIKD8P
    v/tDe5gXLvo2ldj4HuOv5GZGABxy6J4FfY+WakBNHBvJB9khOnx74dxCb58M
    kk/i1j+phPm+v2Z6Brd1shr2wm6pgrNkfCwfK7YQ78V6clN08SDJT+u4oijw
    zKPBCDI+WWwXRbtgP7JBHMF82KhIvd6H9VfEGh4D8n61vTRM4YOW6r5bnSH+
    sLLZriP/4AMfyu3K4fgT91Ir+rHfyXb2mIB7oyPPCn3UUl0fw36GaRTzmQ+X
    ui3sqOMRJATfLDswnAI7DAm8koGlFXLm38Pe99MZ1OCkVB+1MVg7+8ung7Cf
    cgqX8Cct1YT3+2sOwbkXsKKBv/Sp0J+H50s2MvWgvLnaonYSzHqP1UgTx+tU
    jxR9hDOSG5ct4cQ1rhLfYaNsLjtjuCI9aXkK/sHd7yQLd+9Li6EZQz7uGXj+
    E9ejV19iFSXv16U7w5/AXucq92jAaZEi5VdI/UKith+DZ6vl5c3heDGes4Hk
    /f8WuyOqcDuteAh5v/8Js60wLK99KCgVputP0ZhHewlu9D9TDGe1Dpu8gstW
    jaY3wttY4xqewLzXKjvJ9wXxvcP2+XCXV2YE+f4gn5HBEgNH1Rb6jcE2PgUt
    LrDu8aLgJbjb0pLeCX4yxSO0CDPnmbTthDt4Tfv4x7E/f33fRRh24u87Kgar
    S5veZ4S5e9aekYONS3feZoDbCxi1d8MGYf3jn9Df83tZ5/ThFIPqrvfwlZXP
    o8Ywp+32gj54/ZbOr6ZwKcNKywP4xxr+UWfYvalc7CQpv5BymHwvurzz+V0O
    eO3zGyb18Mq3pqhixNsjcR2XeVjOYqdkAVzf/HvqLzzgctbOH3Zsjq/l+o72
    6BH9KgHL8HJ0r4M5jV9PbIDpWjnkiJVvJQtXIZ51PETsmeETobdqgmCeyvqv
    m+GtQoVTlnBqjbWwLHzWWUZ8CePl7V+OcxYw/+910ZNwbW53pjlslvC06S3s
    eY2x2wYOnfg9GQvbfptxcoeT5arb7eGKGPrP/uT74diz5SyMX1EnK/UieMmr
    3rsC4zvx54rxOLxyw/n1Kvh8s1kwzwSFumP1xaYbyBfizm815OG5rZe/noJF
    /Sh7TOEDCnzSanAwU7ygPflebLX3kyDc51rz2ReuN7OhtpL8aTBenUe+L0uf
    ruCH44pnxZh+UKhxjOoN9zEfBPy6vKgD5ywLtyXAar7Ly8dgPxW3p4Gw4AHN
    ZW9YrzlA2ApeaF5Hkw6Tn0MYwBsuKrXlw7uYrs+yw+8mQg99hstt3YqGMX8P
    5//woJ+kUM9vlNhWQtYP2qYsu+FbBZufCMC/Y71rquAFM99XE1j//tM3Sx2E
    X7+mNxmB39MxOI3Am4RTy4bgqoe98eNwSzyPEbGHr5omMW/VTx0v2HGv5lbJ
    KazP1FvKPOCMk+wJxApny41d4KaC7mfSMPmMQ9b7LqPMzTLwCtvirAh8y23c
    8BA8s67ZeAj7jfi/WZEB8IknTubJ8J+Jl7534HyRD+Zkfx7fYc/eC+faKDJc
    wv5eZObGE8VpCvWCW6nlGdhSY1BIH6Ypljx0GtZXynTRgxvmD1OPww8CFbcb
    wwOfma8XdGD9woSRAZe+TJ7bCHeY9M/kzWC9ZM9Syw7vNdU/WwjzeWdkcZL3
    S4cxo8KnfEITVsHfVwS+tcIh82NvLrWjfM/wHemfqB/zYsQBWK4qnfYUXMwd
    080AZzbX/omGC6JSe963oT/Ngsxc4Yc3F8rJ+2Bmm+0RYfCQ769znbBnS9pS
    Mlw64JbbAmuHVSc8gK1/0fnWw9zJ28vq4C5dGp1H5LjPOsU3cOzdYYYHcLv9
    4W9DsLmX0QR5n01/4Pcy+X3NfV3asmtww0JjEtsshVq48Mo4DP7DRTPEC1e/
    OHbHE7Ye1aOThA3pnhSeht9pK76Qhed/zjzVhx85L7TpwDM8b11VYKGR+Jum
    MPvWphZxWL7kNvsJ2Kw1QK2kFfvHopGKHDiTOzziDHzrenhQKxyieFPeEta6
    pJX5Dv7/f3/0P9MszxM=
    "]]]
```

and for Toronto:

```
Polygon[
GeoPosition[CompressedData["
1:eJxd23c8V9/jB3BKRglRKhkZGVkZpUTJVklZUZKsSpQVkpUUKpEiQrSQkb33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"]]]
```

---

Based on the comment by @LouisB, the builtin `Geo` functions only use polygon for the `AdministrativeDivisions` & above but not for cities.

But even for `AdministrativeDivisions` my change in Polygon is not used by the functions. So for example:

If I assign the polygon for Mississauga above to Administrative Division Toronto:

```
Unprotect[Entity];
Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Toronto","Ontario","Canada"}]["Polygon"]="polygon for Mississauga above";
Protect[Entity];
```

Then plot using this:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["City",{"Toronto","Ontario","Canada"}]->2,Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Toronto","Ontario","Canada"}]->1}]
```

It is still using the Toronto polygon for AdministrativeDivision instead of the Mississauga one I assigned.

Comment: `Quit` out of MMA and then restart MMA from scratch.  Now evaluate this `GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity[
    "City", {"Mississauga", "Ontario", "Canada"}] -> 2, 
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Toronto", "Ontario", 
     "Canada"}] -> 1}]`  That gives us a polygon for Toronto.  It's as if MMA plots cities by location and administrative divisions by polygon.  Try changing Mississauga to Toronto to see Toronto plotted as both a city and an AdminDiv.  Question remains of how to associate a polygon to Mississauga.

Comment: @LouisB How did you know that the `Toronto`'s `Entity` exists as an `"AdministrativeDivision"` also inaddition to type `"City"`? I tried to look at `Entity["Country", "Canada"]["AdministrativeDivisions"]` and didn't find `Toronto` there.

Comment: I didn't know it, I just tried it.  I was comparing the properties of the different entities and noticed that Toronto has a Polygon (though its value is Missing on the city).  I was thinking it may be possible to define a new entity that works with GeoRegionValuePlot and I was wondering what type and what properties would be be required to make it work.